# Characteristics of a volatile hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I am trying to get a firm handle on how a variable declared as

```
private volatile HashMap<Object, ArrayList<String>> data;
```

would behave in a multi-threaded environment.

What I understand is that `volatile` means get from main memory and not from the thread cache. That means that if a variable is being updated I will not see the new values until the update is complete and I will not block, rather what I see is the last updated value.  (This is **exactly** what I want BTW.)

My question is when I retrieve the `ArrayList<String>` and add or remove strings to it in thread A while thread B is reading, what exactly is affected by the `volatile` keyword?  The `HashMap` only or is the effect extended to the contents (K and V) of the `HashMap` as well?  That is when thread B gets an `ArrayList<String>` that is currently being modified in thread A what is actually returned is the last value of `ArrayList<String>` that existed before the updated began.

Just to be clear, lets say the update is adding 2 strings.  One string has already been added in thread A when thread B gets the array.  Does thread B get the array as it was before the first string was added?

Comment: Note that `volatile` has to do with the reference, not with the `Object` that is being referenced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> That means that if a variable is being updated I will not see the new values until the update is complete and I will not block, rather what I see is the last updated value

This is your source of confusion. What volatile does is make sure that reads and writes to that field are atomic - so no other threads could ever see a partially written value.

A non-atomic long field (which takes 2 memory addresses on a 32-bit machine) could be read incorrectly if a write operation was preempted after writing to the first address, and before writing to the second address.

Note that the atomicity of reads/writes to a field has nothing to do with updating the inner state of an `HashMap`. Updating the inner state of an `HashMap` entails multiple instructions, which are not atomic as a whole. That's why you'd use locks to synchronize access to the `HashMap`.

Also, since read/write operations on references are *always* atomic, even if the field is not marked as volatile, there is no difference between a volatile and a non-volatile HashMap, *regarding atomicity*. In that case, all volatile does is give you acquire-release semantics. This means that, even though the processor and the compiler are still allowed to slightly reorder your instructions, no instructions may ever be moved above a volatile read or below a volatile write.

Comment: _volatile_ does more than atomic reads and writes. reads and writes to references are always atomic in Java. However, the execution may appear to be non-sequentially consistent, if _volatile_ is not used.

Comment: @nosid yes it does, it introduces half fences, to prevent memory reordering, to a certain degree. I was under the impression that the question was more about the atomicity effect though. I'll add a note regarding this soon.

Comment: I was referring only to _atomicity_, because your whole answer is about _atomicity_, not about _reordering_. The JLS clearly states (17.7): _Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values._

Comment: @nosid Added a paragraph regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

The volatile keyword here is only applicable to HashMap, not the data stored within it, in this case is ArrayList.

As stated in HashMap documentation:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads
> access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
> modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A
> structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
> more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an
> instance already contains is not a structural modification.) This is
> typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally
> encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be
> "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method. This is best
> done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to
> the map:
>
> ```
>  Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The *volatile* keywords neither affects operations on the *HashMap* (e.g. *put*, *get*) nor operations on the *ArrayLists* within the *HashMap*. The *volatile* keywords only affects *reads* and *writes* on this particular reference to the *HashMap*. Again, there can be further references to the same *HashMap*, which are no affected.

If you want to synchronise all operations on:
- the reference
- the *HashMap*
- and the *ArrayList*,
then use an additional *Lock* object for synchronisation as in the following code.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private Map<Object, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

// access reference
synchronized (lock) {
    map = new HashMap<>();
}

// access reference and HashMap
synchronized (lock) {
    return map.contains(42);
}

// access reference, HashMap and ArrayList
synchronized (lock) {
    map.get(42).add("foobar");
}
```

If the reference is not changed, you can use the *HashMap* for synchronization (instead of the *Lock*).